# How to create a tensorflow-federated system by local differential privacy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-federated

I have created a centralized differential privacy system according to the official manual of Tensorflow-federated. However, my research need a local differential privacy system based on Tensorflow-federated. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, all of the default [aggregator implementations for differential privacy](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/aggregators/DifferentiallyPrivateFactory) are indeed differentially private under the central model. However, it is possible to implement local DP mechanisms with TensorFlow-Privacy and TFF.

TFF's default mechanisms add the noise 'on the server', after performing aggregation--but it is possible to implement an instance of [`tensorflow_privacy.DPQuery`](https://www.tensorflow.org/responsible_ai/privacy/api_docs/python/tf_privacy/DPQuery) which will create a TFF aggregator that the noise *locally*, at each client, *before* aggregation. In fact, there are such implementations in TF Privacy, e.g. the [`DistributedSkellamSumQuery`](https://www.tensorflow.org/responsible_ai/privacy/api_docs/python/tf_privacy/DistributedSkellamSumQuery). The noise for this query is [added *inside* `preprocess_record`](https://github.com/tensorflow/privacy/blob/master/tensorflow_privacy/privacy/dp_query/distributed_skellam_query.py#L124), which can logically be computed 'on the clients'. It is this property which makes this query compatible with local differential privacy.

Since `tff.aggregators.DifferentiallyPrivateFactory` is parameterized by DPQueries, any query which has this property is compatible with local DP in TFF. The TFF aggregator implementation [runs the preprocess function at the clients placement](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/v0.31.0/tensorflow_federated/python/aggregators/differential_privacy.py#L355); since the records for a query which has this 'add the noise inside preprocessing' property are therefore noised before being communicated to the server, using an aggregator with a query which has this property in fact will be locally differentially private.